# jquery height and width returning incorrect values in internet explorer 8 (ie8)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, height, width

The following code is working fine in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but not on IE8.  It's always returning the column height as 0 and the width incorrectly.  Ideas?

**jQuery version: 1.9.1**

```
$(function ()
{
    $(window).load(function ()
    {
        // Megamenu
        $("#menu-primary > li").one('mouseenter', function (e)
        {
            var tallestColumnHeight = 0,
            submenuPanelTotalWidth = 0;

            $(".dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu", this).each(function ()
            {
                $(this).load();

                tallestColumnHeight = Math.max(tallestColumnHeight, $(this).height())
                console.log('tallest column ' + tallestColumnHeight);

                submenuPanelTotalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
                console.log('panel width ' + submenuPanelTotalWidth);
            }).height(tallestColumnHeight);

            $(".dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu", this).parent().width(submenuPanelTotalWidth);
        });
    }); 
});
```

What the doctype looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Is the submenu displayed with css `:hover`? Could be a timing issue then.

Comment: It is: ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu { display: block; }

Comment: It's just a wild guess: Maybe the dropdown menu is not yet (completely) rendered when the event handler executes. Hence it's height is 0. Something like that.

Comment: You were right, handling the display with JS instead of CSS fixed it for IE8, will post updated code shortly.

Comment: Ha, too bad I didn't write an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery 2.0: It does no longer support IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that IE8 didn't work well when the element's visibility (display:block) was set via CSS on hover.  Handling the display with JS did the trick (thanks @zeroflagL for the hint):

Code that works (remove the console.log lines of course):

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    $("#menu-primary > li").on('mouseenter', function (e)
    {
        var tallestColumnHeight = 0,
        submenuPanelTotalWidth = 0;

        $(".dropdown-menu", this).show();
            $(".dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu", this).each(function ()
            {
                $(this).load();

                tallestColumnHeight = Math.max(tallestColumnHeight, $(this).height());
                console.log('tallest column ' + tallestColumnHeight);

                submenuPanelTotalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
                console.log('panel width ' + submenuPanelTotalWidth);

            }).height(tallestColumnHeight);
            $(".dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu", this).parent().width(submenuPanelTotalWidth);        
    }).on('mouseleave', function (e)
    {
        $(".dropdown-menu", this).hide();
    });
});
```